# intent setdataandtype sdcard gethomepath

Tags: android, android-intent, path, firemonkey

based on code fragments from stackoverflow with "intents":

```
F_Pdf_File:=    GetHomePath + PathDelim + '_files' + PathDelim + 'lic.pdf';
Intent := TJIntent.Create;
Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
Intent.setDataAndType(StrToJURI( F_Pdf_File),  StringToJString('application/pdf'));
SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
```

the pdf file could not be opened, not in the app and not in SolidExplorer.
In other samples I read about opening files in "sdcard/download".

But my files should be downloaded (beside:some of them direct deliverded to StartUp) and be part of the application (f.e. license agreements) and must not be placed in global directories like download or media:

also important, they shall not be deleted on reboot.

1. is it a good idea to download to HomePath at all ? the files can be big - is "getFilesDir()" the best place ? Solution must work across platforms and dir should be deleted when removing the app...
2. must I first copy the file to /sdcard (or is "getCacheDir()" the right place) before opening ? (performance and mem space)

Sorry, after a lot of googling I became more and more confused about the locations and where to place my files...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you download the files.

Files aren't deleted on reboot, ever. Your app's files, depending on where they are, will be deleted if someone uninstalls your app.

You basically have two locations: internal storage and external storage. If you have external storage in internal memory on the device, *and* the device also has an SD card slot, then an external SD card can hold media files, but these are very much separate from your app.

getFilesDir() describes internal storage's files/ subdirectory; getExternalFilesDir() is the same for external storage. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns the external storage "root".

Performance is not as much an issue as space. Internal storage is more limited.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do in your code. To view a PDF on a device, you need an app that can view PDF, and you need to download the PDF from wherever it exists. Look at DownloadManager for downloading from the web: it downloads to external storage, but you can copy the file to internal storage and delete the external copy when you're finished.

I can't help you with viewing PDF. Several apps do that, but it's not built into Android.

Comment: "Internal storage is more limited" -- on Android 1.x/2.x. On most Android 3.0+ devices, internal and external storage share a partition, and so they have equivalent space.

Comment: f.e. in unix app and data are splittet (/bin/myapp , /usr/<myapp>/lic.pdf; deleted by installer); in win i would make a Folder below (<programfiles>/<app>/myapp.exe, <programfiles>/<app>/<data>/lic.pdf) - but in android I cannot load  pdf from subpath of my "GetHomePath"...